# Fps bar on Kivy apps not disabling on mac os

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, kivy

I used `Config.set('modules', 'monitor', '')` on one of my Kivy apps to get the fps bar, but I can't get it disabled now.

Kivy version -- 1.10.1

I've tried everything and checked every line of code but can't get it disabled. Also if I write a basic code with just

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

imports I still getting the fps bar. I even reinstalled the whole Kivy environment but still I have the fps bar.

These are all the imports that I used in my file which created all the problem.

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

# from kivy.config import Config
# Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
# Config.set('graphics', 'width',  500)
# Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)
# Config.set('modules', 'monitor', '')

from kivy.metrics import *
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (sp(500), sp(300))

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Line, InstructionGroup, Color
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, Property
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder

import random as rnd
import time
```

This is the basic code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Output Image

[image]

Comment: try deleting `HOME/.kivy/config.ini`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you so much! That actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [eyllanesc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) comment I've found a fix to this problem in case anyone else gets into the same problem.

**Note**: Always create a backup of the file.

1. Go to this directory.

   - Windows: `C:\Users\tito\.kivy\config.ini`
   - macOS: `/Users/tito/.kivy/config.ini`
   - Linux: `/home/tito/.kivy/config.ini`
2. Open config.ini
3. Find

   ```
   [modules]
   monitor =
   ```
4. Delete `monitor =` and Save it.

If anything happens just delete the `config.ini` and Kivy will create a new one but all your configurations will reset.